# Chrome crash when trying to see a Youtube video using Adobe Flash

Tags: google-chrome, flash

Every time I visit Youtube on Chrome the page crashes, not just that Flash player has crashed message, the whole page crashes and says nothing about what the problem was caused by.

I have Chrome version 36.0.1985.143 I have Ubuntu 14.04 with the latest updates. Here is the output of about:flash

```
About Flash

Google Chrome   36.0.1985.143 ()
OS  Linux
Flash plugin    14.0.0.177 /opt/google/chrome/PepperFlash/libpepflashplayer.so
--- Crash data ---
Crash Reporting Enable crash reporting to see crash IDs
For more details    https://support.google.com/chrome/?p=ui_usagestat
--- GPU information ---
--- GPU driver, more information ---
Vendor Id   0x1002
Device Id   0x9647
Driver vendor   Mesa
Driver version  10.1.3
Driver date 
Pixel shader version    1.30
Vertex shader version   1.30
GL_VENDOR   X.Org
GL_RENDERER Gallium 0.4 on AMD SUMO
GL_VERSION  3.0 Mesa 10.1.3
GL_EXTENSIONS   GL_ARB_multisample GL_EXT_abgr GL_EXT_bgra GL_EXT_blend_color GL_EXT_blend_minmax GL_EXT_blend_subtract GL_EXT_copy_texture GL_EXT_polygon_offset GL_EXT_subtexture GL_EXT_texture_object GL_EXT_vertex_array GL_EXT_compiled_vertex_array GL_EXT_texture GL_EXT_texture3D GL_IBM_rasterpos_clip GL_ARB_point_parameters GL_EXT_draw_range_elements GL_EXT_packed_pixels GL_EXT_point_parameters GL_EXT_rescale_normal GL_EXT_separate_specular_color GL_EXT_texture_edge_clamp GL_SGIS_generate_mipmap GL_SGIS_texture_border_clamp GL_SGIS_texture_edge_clamp GL_SGIS_texture_lod GL_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB GL_ARB_multitexture GL_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB GL_IBM_multimode_draw_arrays GL_IBM_texture_mirrored_repeat GL_ARB_texture_cube_map GL_ARB_texture_env_add GL_ARB_transpose_matrix GL_EXT_blend_func_separate GL_EXT_fog_coord GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays GL_EXT_secondary_color GL_EXT_texture_env_add GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic GL_EXT_texture_lod_bias GL_INGR_blend_func_separate GL_NV_blend_square GL_NV_light_max_exponent GL_NV_texgen_reflection GL_NV_texture_env_combine4 GL_S3_s3tc GL_SUN_multi_draw_arrays GL_ARB_texture_border_clamp GL_ARB_texture_compression GL_EXT_framebuffer_object GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc GL_EXT_texture_env_combine GL_EXT_texture_env_dot3 GL_MESA_window_pos GL_NV_packed_depth_stencil GL_NV_texture_rectangle GL_ARB_depth_texture GL_ARB_occlusion_query GL_ARB_shadow GL_ARB_texture_env_combine GL_ARB_texture_env_crossbar GL_ARB_texture_env_dot3 GL_ARB_texture_mirrored_repeat GL_ARB_window_pos GL_EXT_stencil_two_side GL_EXT_texture_cube_map GL_NV_depth_clamp GL_NV_fog_distance GL_APPLE_packed_pixels GL_APPLE_vertex_array_object GL_ARB_draw_buffers GL_ARB_fragment_program GL_ARB_fragment_shader GL_ARB_shader_objects GL_ARB_vertex_program GL_ARB_vertex_shader GL_ATI_draw_buffers GL_ATI_texture_env_combine3 GL_ATI_texture_float GL_EXT_shadow_funcs GL_EXT_stencil_wrap GL_MESA_pack_invert GL_NV_primitive_restart GL_ARB_depth_clamp GL_ARB_fragment_program_shadow GL_ARB_half_float_pixel GL_ARB_occlusion_query2 GL_ARB_point_sprite GL_ARB_shading_language_100 GL_ARB_sync GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object GL_ATI_blend_equation_separate GL_EXT_blend_equation_separate GL_OES_read_format GL_ARB_color_buffer_float GL_ARB_pixel_buffer_object GL_ARB_texture_compression_rgtc GL_ARB_texture_float GL_ARB_texture_rectangle GL_ATI_texture_compression_3dc GL_EXT_packed_float GL_EXT_pixel_buffer_object GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1 GL_EXT_texture_compression_rgtc GL_EXT_texture_mirror_clamp GL_EXT_texture_rectangle GL_EXT_texture_sRGB GL_EXT_texture_shared_exponent GL_ARB_framebuffer_object GL_EXT_framebuffer_blit GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample GL_EXT_packed_depth_stencil GL_ARB_vertex_array_object GL_ATI_separate_stencil GL_ATI_texture_mirror_once GL_EXT_draw_buffers2 GL_EXT_draw_instanced GL_EXT_gpu_program_parameters GL_EXT_texture_array GL_EXT_texture_compression_latc GL_EXT_texture_integer GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode GL_EXT_timer_query GL_OES_EGL_image GL_ARB_copy_buffer GL_ARB_depth_buffer_float GL_ARB_draw_instanced GL_ARB_half_float_vertex GL_ARB_instanced_arrays GL_ARB_map_buffer_range GL_ARB_texture_rg GL_ARB_texture_swizzle GL_ARB_vertex_array_bgra GL_EXT_texture_swizzle GL_EXT_vertex_array_bgra GL_NV_conditional_render GL_AMD_conservative_depth GL_AMD_draw_buffers_blend GL_AMD_seamless_cubemap_per_texture GL_AMD_shader_stencil_export GL_ARB_ES2_compatibility GL_ARB_blend_func_extended GL_ARB_debug_output GL_ARB_draw_buffers_blend GL_ARB_draw_elements_base_vertex GL_ARB_explicit_attrib_location GL_ARB_fragment_coord_conventions GL_ARB_provoking_vertex GL_ARB_sampler_objects GL_ARB_seamless_cube_map GL_ARB_shader_stencil_export GL_ARB_shader_texture_lod GL_ARB_texture_cube_map_array GL_ARB_texture_multisample GL_ARB_texture_rgb10_a2ui GL_ARB_uniform_buffer_object GL_ARB_vertex_type_2_10_10_10_rev GL_EXT_provoking_vertex GL_EXT_texture_snorm GL_MESA_texture_signed_rgba GL_NV_texture_barrier GL_ARB_get_program_binary GL_ARB_robustness GL_ARB_shader_bit_encoding GL_ARB_timer_query GL_ARB_transform_feedback2 GL_ARB_transform_feedback3 GL_NV_vdpau_interop GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt3 GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt5 GL_ARB_base_instance GL_ARB_conservative_depth GL_ARB_internalformat_query GL_ARB_map_buffer_alignment GL_ARB_shading_language_420pack GL_ARB_shading_language_packing GL_ARB_texture_storage GL_ARB_transform_feedback_instanced GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample_blit_scaled GL_EXT_transform_feedback GL_AMD_shader_trinary_minmax GL_ARB_clear_buffer_object GL_ARB_invalidate_subdata GL_ARB_texture_storage_multisample GL_ARB_vertex_attrib_binding GL_KHR_debug GL_ARB_texture_mirror_clamp_to_edge GL_ARB_vertex_type_10f_11f_11f_rev
```

Comment: Regular flash has been deprecated on 14.04 and Chrome since before 14.04 came out, so you really had to do a significant amount of finagling to generate this problem.  Use pepper-flash.

Comment: it was a question, and even if the software is depreciated I didn't know that and someone should make an answer with how to SOLVE IT...sorry if I'm seeming agitated but just because I have old software doesn't mean it's off topic, it means I should be told how to update or replace it

Comment: Close voters: Why is Pepper Flash Player in Chrome off topic? The pepperflashplugin-nonfree package in the Ubuntu Software Center is installed by downloading Google Chrome and then unpacking and installing the included Pepper Flash Player. If "Chrome" was changed to "Chromium" there would not be anything off topic.

Comment: @karel I'd guess it's a bug and hence marked off-topic. Note the close reason. Voting to leave closed.

Comment: @muru It's OK with me to call insects bugs because that's what they are, but I don't like calling an accepted answer question off topic because of a suspected bug. The derivation of the word "bug" is that an engineer found that a computer glitch was caused by a *physical* bug inside a huge old mainframe computer.

Comment: @karel Answers get accepted and upvoted because of the answer, not the question. There's a reason why the Reversal badge exists (if not yet awarded on AU). We all know the story of Grace Hopper.

Comment: I don't see how this is off topic. If it's something that can be resolved easily then it's a question about a problem that has a fix. The fix was updating to a newer kind of flash because the bug has been fixed there and a patch has been released

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are having an issue with Flash player in Google Chrome, try these troubleshooting steps:

1. Go to `chrome://plugins` and check "Always allowed" under the Flash plugin.
2. If you have more than one Flash plugin installed, please disable one version by going to  chrome://plugins, click on "Details" in the upper right corner, and "Disable" under one of the two Flash plugins.
3. Load the YouTube content in Incognito mode to see if there is any improvement.
4. The YouTube HTML5 Player is the default for playing videos on YouTube in Chrome. Visit the [YouTube HTML5 Video Player](https://www.youtube.com/html5) webpage to check if the YouTube HTML5 Player is enabled in your web browser.
5. Try to reset your [Chrome browser settings](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3296214?hl=en).

Answer (score 1):

I run into this issue occasionally and it's a strange one for me. Check your disk space. If I try to access a page with a youtube embedded link, and my `/home/username/.cache` folder (which i've intentionally mounted as a RAM drive) is full, Chrome will crash. It'll happily surf along otherwise removing old stuff as necessary but if I hit a YouTube embed, it dies. Just an extra thing for you to check.

Comment: But it also happens while viewing YouTube on their official site YouTube.com, not just embedded links. Thanks for the suggestion though, you reminded me I need to clean out my caches for a lot of stuff